# Why does my mongoid server description change from primary to primary all the time?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I see these a lot, a lot:

```
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'primary' to 'primary'.
```

Is there a particular misconfiguration that's causing this, or is this a part of normal operation?

my /etc/mongodb.conf:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

replication:
  replSetName: something
```

Comment: Replica sets hold ["elections"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) and checks quite a bit. It would seem here that the underlying ["moped"](https://github.com/mongoid/moped) base driver ( which is where the logging comes from AFAIK ) has this polling check for replica set members and logs them on a regular basis. All drivers actually poll the replica set in this way, it just seems that "moped" is noisy about it.